# Is there a way to Toast everyone on a Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

new to Google Apps Script here.

I have a custom script that runs via button, and I'm curious as to whether there is way to toast all the users on a Spreadsheet, instead of just the user who executes the script. I'm not interested in emailing them as they would have to have another tab to look at it. I'd like the toast to be visible to everyone on the sheet.

```
function addComment() {

var activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var newSheet = activeSpreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
var unitAdj = newSheet.getRange("W3").getValue();
var rangeFormulaP = ("$P$" + unitAdj + "");  
var rangeFormulaO = ("$O$" + unitAdj + "");  
var emailID = (Session.getActiveUser().getEmail());
var emailFormula = ('"' + emailID + '"');
var rows = newSheet.getRange("W2").getValue();
var newRows = (rows)+1;
var rangeFormulaA = ("$A$" + rows + "");
var rangeFormulaB = ("$B$" + rows + "");
var rangeFormulaC = ("$C$" + rows + "");
var rangeFormulaK = ("$K$" + unitAdj + "");
var incidentNumber = newSheet.getRange("C5").getValue();

newSheet.insertRowsAfter(rows, 1);
newSheet.getRange(rangeFormulaA).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("hh:mm:ss");  
newSheet.getRange(rangeFormulaA).setHorizontalAlignment("left");
newSheet.getRange(rangeFormulaB).setValue('=VLOOKUP(' + emailFormula + ', Library!H151:I159,2,FALSE)');
newSheet.getRange(rangeFormulaA).setFontSize(14);
newSheet.getRange(rangeFormulaB).setFontSize(14);
newSheet.getRange(newRows,3,1,6).merge();
SpreadsheetApp.flush();
newSheet.getRange(rangeFormulaO).copyTo(newSheet.getRange(rangeFormulaP), {contentsOnly: true});
newSheet.getRange(rangeFormulaB).copyTo(newSheet.getRange(rangeFormulaB), {contentsOnly: true});   
var comments = newSheet.getRange(rangeFormulaP).getValue();
newSheet.getRange(rangeFormulaC).setValue(comments);
newSheet.getRange(rangeFormulaC).setFontSize(14);
newSheet.getRange("W2").setValue(newRows);
newSheet.getRange(rangeFormulaK).setValue("");
activeSpreadsheet.toast("EVENT COMMENTS UPDATED", incidentNumber, 10);
```

I would like that toast to get sent to everyone that is on the spreadsheet so they know to check the page. The function adds a new row to the bottom of a "comments section" on the sheet.

Comment: "I'm curious as to whether there is way to toast all the users on a Spreadsheet, instead of just the user who executes the script". When you say "all the users on a Spreadsheet", do you mean users who have the Spreadsheet open at the same time as when the custom script is run? Do your users log on to use the spreadsheet.  Would you please post the script in your questions?

Comment: @Tedinoz Yes to your question-all the users who have the Spreadsheet open when the script is ran. Everyone who can edit is logged in (Editors are who I'm concerned about). Added the function to the post.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT (update)**

It's not possible to trigger the UI of another user, as the script can only run for the user who executes it.

A workaround could be manually writting a message in the Sheet's [chat](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2494891?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en), which would notify all the users currently looking at the Sheet.

---

If you are referring to [pop up](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#toast(String)) a message for anyone who has access to the Sheet, then this would execute every time someone opens it. Keep in mind that this won't run for users with only Read access:

```
function onOpen(){
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast("hello there");

}
```

More info about the onOpen Trigger [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onopene).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've added the code to my OP to help clarify.

Comment: I'm afraid that is not possible. I changed my answer.